# Iterate on all weeks between start, finish date

Tags: java, datetime

I have two Date objects, start and finish. I want to iterate them on a weekly basis, i.e. if there are exactly 4 weeks in between (calendar weeks, not just 7 days after each other), I want 4 iterations and in each iteration I want to get the actual start and end Dates.

I'm currently hacking up an Iterable for the purpose, but I'm thinking if it can be achieved easily with for example Joda Time or a smart custom method.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I must repeat that I need weeks as in calendar, not seven days after each other. If my start date is on a random day in the week (for example friday), my first iteration should contain [friday,sunday] not [friday,friday+7 days]. Solution posted as answer.**

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: The question is, how to achieve this in Java.

Comment: okay. can you please explain with one example so it will be more clear.

Comment: Start: 2000. 01. 01. End: 2000. 01. 15. I want two iterations, [s:01:01, e:01:07], [s:01:08: e: 01.15]. Thats all. An Iterable and its Iterator would help, but it's just too much code for a considerably primitive feature.

Comment: Do you have to use the Date object?  You're going to keep getting suggestions to use Calendar objects since the majority of Date's functionality is deprecated as of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.  Also, what is expected to happen when the dates do not form a complete week, an example might be what if there is 1 week and 5 days between the start and end dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, here is a working solution that fulfills my requirements (note that adding seven days to some day won't produce a calendar week in most cases, only if it's a monday!)
This code uses Joda Time API.

```
private static List<Interval> getWeeks(final DateTime start, final DateTime finish)
{
    final int weekLeaps = Weeks.weeksBetween(start, finish).getWeeks();
    if (weekLeaps == 0) {
        return ImmutableList.of(new Interval(start, finish));
    } else {
        // We hop sundays at least once
        final ImmutableList.Builder<Interval> resBuild = ImmutableList.<Interval> builder();

        // First week
        DateTime wStart = start;
        DateTime wEnd = rollToWeekEnd(start);
        resBuild.add(new Interval(wStart, wEnd));

        // Other weeks
        for (int i = 0; i < weekLeaps; i++) {
            wStart = wEnd.plusSeconds(1);
            DateTime actWeekEnd = rollToWeekEnd(wStart);
            wEnd = actWeekEnd.isBefore(finish) ? actWeekEnd : finish;
            resBuild.add(new Interval(wStart, wEnd));
        }

        return resBuild.build();
    }
}

private static DateTime rollToWeekEnd(final DateTime from)
{
    return from.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY)
        .withHourOfDay(23)
        .withMinuteOfHour(59)
        .withSecondOfMinute(59)
        .withMillisOfSecond(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9 there is a nice [LocalDate.datesUntil](https://medium.com/@ggajos/jdk9-iterate-days-with-localdate-datesuntil-db5d73ec3545) method. There is also an easy way to adjust time within a week boundaries using [TemporalAdjusters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-).

```
    int numOfWeeks = 4;

    // First iteration with alignment
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate endOfTheFirstWeek = start.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    out.println(String.format("[%s,%s]", start, endOfTheFirstWeek));

    // Remaining iterations
    endOfTheFirstWeek
            .datesUntil(endOfTheFirstWeek.plusWeeks(numOfWeeks - 1), Period.ofWeeks(1))
            .forEach(it -> {
                LocalDate from = it.plusDays(1);
                LocalDate to = from.plusWeeks(1);
                out.println(String.format("[%s,%s]", from, to));
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate using Calendar and WEEK_OF_YEAR:

```
 int startWeek;
 int finishWeek;
 int diff;
 SimpleDateFormat sdf;
 Calendar cal;
 Calendar startCountingCal;
 Date startDate;
 Date finishDate;
 String startDateS = "01/01/2013";
 String finishDateS = "01/05/2013";

 sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

 startDate = sdf.parse(startDateS);
 finishDate = sdf.parse(finishDateS);

 cal = Calendar.getInstance();

 cal.setTime(startDate);
 startWeek = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);    

 cal.setTime(finishDate);
 finishWeek = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

 diff = finishWeek - startWeek;

 startCountingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
 startCountingCal.setTime(startDate);   

 for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {

     if (i==0) {
        System.out.println("WEEK " + i + " start: " + sdf.format(startCountingCal.getTime()));
        startCountingCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        System.out.println("WEEK " + i + " start: " + sdf.format(startCountingCal.getTime()));  
    } else {
        System.out.println("WEEK " + i + " start: " + sdf.format(startCountingCal.getTime()));
        startCountingCal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        System.out.println("WEEK " + i + " start: " + sdf.format(startCountingCal.getTime()));  
    }

}
```

Output:

```
WEEK 0 start: 01/01/2013
WEEK 0 start: 08/01/2013
WEEK 1 start: 08/01/2013
WEEK 1 start: 15/01/2013
WEEK 2 start: 15/01/2013
WEEK 2 start: 22/01/2013
WEEK 3 start: 22/01/2013
WEEK 3 start: 29/01/2013
....
etc.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but you forward by 7 days, not weeks as in the calendar. If my start date is not on monday, but for example on saturday, my first iteration should last only two days (saturday-sunday), not seven. If you pick a random day in the calendar and add 7 days to it, you have a little chance of getting a valid monday-sunday calendar week. I'll prepared some code, adding it now here.

Comment: Also, using Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR can mess up output if the range overlaps some year. Say, if you use it and you want weeks between last week of december and first week of january, you will get 51 weeks, but it's actually 1.